# Android start download without Download file popup of 1DM

Tags: java, android

(I am new to Android.) I want an android app which download the file from url, i have refereed this document to send download link from my app to 1DM+ https://www.apps2sd.info/idmp/faq?id=35

This works like this

[App screenshot after triggering download](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQAWI.jpg)

What i want is to avoid this window. download should automatically start without user interaction.

```java
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button = findViewById(R.id.download);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.v("TAG", "On CLick Called");
                Log.v("Path", Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);

                manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                String pdfFileUrl = "https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf";

                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("idm.internet.download.manager.plus", "idm.internet.download.manager.Downloader"));
                intent.setData(Uri.parse(pdfFileUrl));
                startActivity(intent);
        })
});
```

Thanks

I tried enabling Skip download editor options from 1DM -> Settings -> General -> Skip download editor.

but no luck.

Comment: Dont let another app download a file as when it is saved to storage your app will not even have access unless the other app delivers a content scheme uri which lets you access the file with the file provider of the other app. Did you think of that?

Comment: Why using another app if your app can do it with very little code?

Comment: Yes I can download file using the download manager in my app itself, but consider this, what if download file is big, 6gb 8gb or more then in case of network connectivity problem or download link failed then There is no way to again resume the download. If it's from 1DM, then i can again provide download link then download can be resumed. Thanks.

Comment: Ok. But that has nothing to do with the problems i mentioned. Doesnt it matter you that your app is not the owner of the file? That was what i asked.

Comment: Sorry about that, yes that is totally fine if my app is not the owner of the file. I just want file to be downloaded to device.

Comment: You should write the programmer(s) of that app for that feature or the API.